# How to remove superuser on the system in Django?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I was doing some project by using django
and I realized that I forgot to activate virtualenv.

I already made some changes and applied it not on the venv,
and created superuser on the system.

1. How to find any changes on the system?
2. how to remove superuser that I made on the system
   and what are the cmd commands for that?

Comment: You aren't writing a letter here. Please format it as a question description. Also, Please consider revising the  question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't setup an additional database for your project and you have used `django-admin startproject` you'll just have a standard django setup, and you will be using sqlite. With this setup, your database is stored in a file in your root directory (for the project) called `db.sqlite3`.

This is where the super-user you have created will be stored. So it does not matter if the virtualenv was activated or not. Your superuser will have been created in the right place.

TLDR: No need to worry, the superuser you created will most likely be in the right place.

Comment: Thank you so much and I really appreciate it! Now it's very clear! If may I ask, what are things that I should really be careful with not using the venv? Because I did almost every work on the venv and there was some changes such as adding classes and functions stuffs like that without using venv yesterday, so I am actually very worrying about the changes I already made and applied it to the system can cause any problems later on if I am using same names or kinds of classes or functions in different projects.

Comment: You're more than welcome. The virtual environment takes care of all of the python dependencies you install. (anytime you run `pip install x`). You can see what is installed in your virtual environment, by activating the environment and then typing `pip freeze`, so long as everything you've installed that you need is listed there, then you're all good.

Comment: That's really good to know! Once again, thank you so much for your help! How kind and nice you are! Hope you and your family are always well and safe! thanks!